# IE 5 only hack CSS (newsletter)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, newsletter

I have this template wich be used as newsletter:

[image]

Where you can see how is rendering in IE5 and IE6 (later versions are as i want, like IE5   :O  )

With the markup like:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="text-align:left;position:relative;wmargin:0 auto;padding:25px 25px;padding-bottom:85px;background: url(http://toniweb.us/m/demos/bgPildoraFormativa.jpg) center  bottom no-repeat;display:inline-block;">
     <table>   <!-- content here -->  </table>
</div>
```

link: http://toniweb.us/m/demos/

As you can see i have

```
width:600px;
*width:600px;
_width:650px;
```

What should i place in order to get same rendering in all browsers? i was thinking that instead of applying the hack to ie6 i should apply it to ie5 and let 6 grow

Comment: wait, ie5? you can't be serious!

Comment: i know buddy... i know.. but outlook and other services render the same :(

Comment: width/**/:600px; should work only for IE5. You can find some more hacks here http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/63  (not, that I would a big fan of css hacks :)) )